# trouble with smooth shading 2.8

Tags: mesh, shaders

hey guys so i got my model to the point where i am trying to shade smooth ive got no modifiers or anything just a model i put together. on the bridge of the nose and the back of the lower head there is some weird shading happening. heres some pictures of what im doing, does anyone know whats causing this?
[image]
[image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have face normals facing the wrong way in that stripe along the front of the face. Try recalculating them outside and it might go away.

You can show normals in blender 2.8 by clicking on the overlays menu in the 3d viewport

[image: View normals in overlay 2.8]

You can recalculate the normals on the outside of the mesh with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> if that truly is your issue.

Note that you can only recalculate normals on geometry that you have selected, so go to face mode, then select all with <kbd>A</kbd> before you use the shortcut.

Comment: That was the issue. show nowrmals is very helpful too. thanks bud!